# Number formatting Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am looking for a pipe that transforms like below, just wanted to round 2 decimal points.

I tried `[ngModel]="item.value | number number:'1.0-X'"`, but it's not working in all cases

```
239.779 > 239.78
0.674 > 0.67
35355.453 > 35355.45
```

Comment: What do you mean *"looking for"*? In what cases did the [`DecimalPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) not work? If you *always* want 2dp, for example, setting `minFractionDigits` to 0 doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tried [ngModel]="item.value | number number:'1.2-2'", but 'minIntegerDigits' I dont know how to set since it depends the response value

Comment: So *not* always 2dp? Did you try setting the appropriate value in the string argument?

Comment: decimal points(dp) always 2, but the value before decimal(minIntegerDigits) is always different

Comment: So not always 1 as shown? Same question.

Comment: yes, its not always 1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

**x**.x-x **minIntegerDigits**: The minimum number of integer digits before the decimal point. Default is 1.

x.**x**-x **minFractionDigits**: The minimum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.

x.x-**x** **maxFractionDigits**: The maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

For exactly two decimals and at least one number before decimal you can write like this:

`[ngModel]="item.value | number:'1.2-2'"`

or since minIntegerDigits default is 1: `[ngModel]="item.value | number:'.2-2'"`

If you are interested in locale-specific configurations you can read this article:

- [Custom Angular Pipes and Dynamic Locale](https://medium.com/dailyjs/dynamic-locales-in-angular-dd9a527ebe1f)

Answer (score 1):

Seperate the banana binding to:
 event (ngModelChange) and property [ngModel] parts
(ngModelChange)="Rate1=$event"  [ngModel]="Rate1 |  number:'1.2-2' ".

where 1.2-2 is as follows:
Decimal representation options, specified by a string in the following format:
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}.

You may use it according to your requirements.

Also refer to-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-pipe-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html